# Select a certain value when there are duplicates, while untying on highest date

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have two tables A and B. The common key between the two tables is "key". I am joining the two tables to get the following table: ID, Date, Value. This is the code I use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.ID, A.Date, A.Value
FROM       A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.key = B.key
```

For a certain ID it is ok to have multiple dates but these dates should be different. When the same date appears more than once, a different column called "Date2" should be checked in table A and select only the value with the most recent "Date2"

Example from Table A:

| Date | Date2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2000 | 01-02-2000 | 20 |
| 01-01-2000 | 01-03-2003 | 40 |

In the final table only the second line should be present because the Date2 value is more recent.

I am not sure how to go about with this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Show us some data from table B too, and also _specify_ the expected result - i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: In table B I have only an ID and the "key" on which I am joining the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DBMS supports window functions, you should use `FIRST_VALUE` on both "*B.ID*" and "*A.Value*", while:

- partitioning on "*Date*"
- ordering on "*Date2*" descendently

This will ensure that each "*A.Date*" will have only one record, whose "*B.ID*" and "*Value*" will be the highest possible.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       FIRST_VALUE(B.ID) OVER(PARTITION BY A.Date ORDER BY A.Date2 DESC) AS ID,
       A.Date,
       FIRST_VALUE(A.Value) OVER(PARTITION BY A.Date ORDER BY A.Date2 DESC) AS Value
FROM       A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.key = B.key
```

If your ID is the same across the same "*A.Date*", you can replace the first window function with only "*B.ID*".

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, you can modify your SQL query to include a subquery that selects the row with the most recent Date2 for each unique combination of ID and Date. Here's an updated version of your query:

```sql
SELECT B.ID, A.Date, A.Value
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.key = B.key
WHERE (A.ID, A.Date) IN (
    SELECT ID, Date
    FROM A
    GROUP BY ID, Date
    HAVING MAX(Date2)
)
```

Comment: The problem is that in table A I do not have an ID column. I have only Date, Date2, Value and Key. In table B, I have only the ID and Key columns.

Comment: Maybe you can `GROUP BY key, Date`and `SELECT key, Date`